# Convert from mm of water to Coefficient of pressure (Cp)

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

Okay,

I have this value in mmH<sub>2</sub>O (2.650) and am not sure where to go next to convert it to aerodynamic parameter pressure coefficient please?

1. mmH<sub>2</sub>O * 9.8066 = N/m<sup>2</sup>
2. ???? What do do next please?

I have Patm and P from pitot tube

Comment: What units are a "aerodynamic parameter pressure coefficient" in? Bar, Pascals, inHg? Atmospheres?

Comment: This question is **very** light on details. Could you please elaborate further.

Comment: you need much more data, Pc=(Pstream-Pfreestream)/(1/2.Rho free stream.Vfreestream^2).

Comment: What’s Pc please?

Comment: I think Cp is dimensionless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pressure coefficient is a parameter for studying both incompressible/compressible fluids such as water and air. The relationship between the dimensionless coefficient and the dimensional numbers is:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_coefficient

Does this help? Obviously, you'll need to know/have more than just a single parameter.

Comment: Hi, I’m still a little confused please- I have Patmospheric and P from pitot tube. Is Patmsohperic the P infinity you wrote please and P pitot just the P please?

Comment: The advice I found online: "In situations where all components in a system are under the same pressure (i.e. atmospheric 'pressure), the atmospheric pressure can be ignored because it acts on everything in every direction. Otherwise, when you are looking at pressure differences between a reference pressure and an external (i.e. 'freestream') pressure, like in a pitot tube, then you must obviously consider the different pressures. However, the simplest way to avoid the confusion is to account for everything all the time, and always consider pressures as P1, P2, etc., ignoring the terminology.

Comment: Also, in the attached Wiki article, you can find the definition of each pressure term by clicking on the "blue" texts that will link you to further explanations.

Comment: Another two help resources. https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/VirtualAero/BottleRocket/airplane/pitot.html, https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pressure-coefficient-d_1486.html#:~:text=The%20%EE%80%80pressure%20coefficient%EE%80%81%20is%20is%20the%20ratio%20of,%3D%20flow%20velocity%20%28m%2Fs%29%20dh%20%3D%20head%20%28m%29